# C++ интерпретация uint8_t

Tags: c++

На моём компютере uint8_t интерпретируется как число. А на других устройствах тоже самое? Или может интерпретироватся как символ?

Comment: Конечно! Как скажете - так и интерпретируется... Символ же - это и есть число.

Comment: интерпретация uint8_t зависит от Вас.

Comment: C вероятностью, чуть меньшей, чем единица, `std::uint8_t` есть псевдоним для `unsigned char`. Так что как вам его интерпретировать - решайте сами.

Comment: Полностью переписывая содержимое вопроса, вы обесцениваете труд людей, ответивших на ваш вопрос.

Comment: @nick_n_a так ответ ниже от 30 декабря 2020, а вопрос автор изменял сегодня в 7:20, см. [историю правок](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1225658/revisions).

Comment: Я уже увидел историю правок insolor правильно откат сделал. Просто я видел версию 20 минут назад про производительность и не успел его прочесть, поэтому не мог понять в чём прикол.

Comment: @nick_n_a кроме имеющегося ответа про тип `uint8_t` других ответов я не видел. Просто я прочитал вопрос про производительность ссылок/указателей. Начал читать ответ, а он про `uint8_t`. Какое-то несоответствие, вызывающее недоумение. Благо сайт хранит историю правок, и она в данном случае на стороне отвечающего.

Comment: @ТарасПрогер, если у тебя появился новый вопрос, стоит задать его отдельно, а не полностью менять существующий, на который уже дан ответ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да, почти на всех системах это так (в той степени на сколько я понял то что зашифровано в вопросе). Он будет «интерпретироваться как число».

`uint8_t` почти всегда (если он объявлен) является псевдонимом `unsigned char`, а `int8_t` — `signed char`.

Но в C++ `unsigned char`, `signed char` и `char` — это три разных типа.

> Здесь бы некорректный пример, который был удалён.

И это не зависит от того, является ли сам `char` знаковым типом или нет (стандарт допускает оба варианта).

Comment: самый лучший ответ! Благодарю!

Comment: `std::cout << (  signed char) 'a' << std::endl; //< число` Контрпримеры: [g++](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/89e30c0e4fe8cae6), [clang](https://ideone.com/1op4aP), [vc++](https://rextester.com/YQXK66888).

Comment: @ДжонниКэтсвилл, действительно, я какую-то глупость написал в примере... имел в виде, что все эти три вызова будут инстанцировать разные шаблоны и думал, что в stl это используется... очевидно, тут ошибся не проверив... тогда осталось угадать, что OP всё же имел под «будет интерпретироваться как число»... скорей всего ответ лежит в плоскости той коллизии, что разные char — разные типы, хотя я уже не тау уверен в этом...

Comment: @ТарасПрограммер, пример в ответе был неверным, см. выше... про что всё же вопрос был?